# Adding and removing the item into wish list like flipkart

Tags: android, notifydatasetchanged

I want to add / remove the item into wishlist. I am getting one response from Api, so in that i have one tag is_wishlist=true/false, when I am launching an application based on that value I am showing its in wishlist by changing an icon, but now issue is if am changing that wishlist status like from adding to remobing to adding, in Api i am getting response sucessfully, but i am unable to change the icons. This is my code. can any one help me how to remove or add items into wishlist

[image: this is my image when i am launching application]

```
package com.example.user.smgapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Prd_grid_adapter extends BaseAdapter {


    List<HashMap<String, String>> Category_listData;
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    Context context;
    Typeface face;
    String wishList_url, remove_wishList_url;
    Cursor cursor;
    NavigationDrawer nav = new NavigationDrawer();

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public Prd_grid_adapter(Activity context, List<HashMap<String, String>> aList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Category_listData = aList;
        /*/for(int i=1;i<aList.size();i++)
        {
            Category_listData.add(aList.get(i));
        }*/
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Category_listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView name, price, original_price;
        ImageView img, wish_list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;
        this.face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_view, null);
        holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.p_name);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.p_img);
        holder.wish_list = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.wish_list);
        holder.price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.p_price);
        holder.original_price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.orginal_p);
        map = Category_listData.get(position);
        holder.name.setTypeface(face);
        holder.name.setText(map.get("product_name"));
        Log.e("wish list staus..", "wishlist status.." + map.get("is_wishlist"));
        if (map.get("is_wishlist").equals("0")) {
            holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_wishlist);
        } else {
            holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlist);
        }


        holder.wish_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SingletonActivity.custidstr.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ur not logged in,Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("Alert!");
                    builder.setMessage("Ur not logged in")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                }


                            });
                    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                    builder.show();

                } else {
                    wishList_url = SingletonActivity.API_URL + "api/add_wishlist.php?customer_id=" + SingletonActivity.custidstr + "&product_id=" + Category_listData.get(position).get("product_id");
                    remove_wishList_url = SingletonActivity.API_URL + "api/remove_item_wishlist.php?customerid=" + SingletonActivity.custidstr + "&productid=" + Category_listData.get(position).get("product_id");
                    Log.e("wishlist api..", "wish list api.." + wishList_url);
                    Log.e("remove wishlist api..", "remove wish list api.." + remove_wishList_url);
                    v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
                    String wish_status = map.get("is_wishlist");
                    Log.e("wish status..", "wish status.." + wish_status);
                    int stat = Integer.parseInt(wish_status);
                   // notifyDataSetChanged();

                    /*if (wish_status=="Product already exists in wishlist"){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"removed....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        nav.removeFromwishList(remove_wishList_url);
                        holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_wishlist);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nav.addTowishList(wishList_url);
                        Toast.makeText(context,"addedd..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlist);
                    }*/
                    if (stat == 0) {
                        nav.addTowishList(wishList_url);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "addedd..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlist);
                 //       notifyDataSetChanged();
                    /*   ((Activity)context).finish();
                        Intent i=   ((Activity) context).getIntent();
                        context.startActivity(i);*/

                      //

                    } else {
                        nav.removeFromwishList(remove_wishList_url);
                        holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_wishlist);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "removed....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      /* ((Activity)context).finish();
                        Intent i=   ((Activity) context).getIntent();
                        context.startActivity(i);*/
                  //      notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                   /* v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
                    if (v.isActivated()){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"addedd..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlist);
                        nav.addTowishList(wishList_url);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"removed....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        nav.removeFromwishList(remove_wishList_url);
                        holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_wishlist);
                    }*/


                }


            }
        });


        if (map.get("special_price").equals("0.00")) {
            holder.price.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // holder.o_price.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.original_price.setText("Rs." + map.get("product_price"));
            holder.original_price.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.product_price_txt);

        } else {
            holder.price.setText("Rs." + map.get("special_price"));
            holder.original_price.setText("Rs." + map.get("product_price"));
            holder.original_price.setPaintFlags(holder.original_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }
       /* holder.price.setText("Rs." + map.get("special_price"));
        holder.original_price.setText("Rs."+map.get("product_price"));
        holder.original_price.setPaintFlags(holder.original_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);*/
        Picasso.with(context).load(map.get("product_image")).placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .fit().into(holder.img);
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: you have check the `status` statement if it is `true` then set `Image1` otherwise set `Image2`.

Comment: I am doing that, see in that code

Comment: @Yamuna hello. have you solved this issue? please share solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlist);
```

to this

```
Resources resources = getResources();
holder.wish_list.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.wishlist));
```

and do the same in `else` part and check the output..

> Note :
>
> `getResources().getDrawable` is deprecated.
>
> You can try **`ContextCompat.getDrawable`**:
>
> `holder.wish_list.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
>   R.drawable.wishlist));`

**UpDate :**

check this way.

```
if(state == true){
  // here is default icon and set api value and send it

}else{

// here is click wishlist icon and set api value and send it
}
```

**UpDate 2 :**

```
public class FragmentOne_Adapter extends CursorAdapter {

        FragmentOne_DbAdapter dbHelper;

        public FragmentOne_Adapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            dbHelper = new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);
            dbHelper.open();
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            final int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("artist"));
            String volume = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("volume"));
            final String favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("favorite"));
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("number"));

            // Populate fields with extracted properties
            holder.txtTitle.setText(title);
            holder.txtArtist.setText(artist);
            holder.txtVolume.setText(volume);
            holder.txtNumber.setText(number);

            if (favorite.matches("0")) {
                holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
            } else {
                if (favorite.matches("1")) {
                    holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
                } else {
                    holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                }
            }

            holder.buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (arg0 != null) {
                        FragmentOne_DbAdapter database = new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);
                        database.open();
                        if (favorite.matches("0")) {
                            database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "1");
                            holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
                        } else if (favorite.matches("1")) {
                            database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "0");
                            holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                        }
                    }
                    FragmentOne_Adapter.this.changeCursor(dbHelper.fetchAllPlayer1());
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//            View rowView = ((LayoutInflater) context
//                    .getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(
//                    R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, parent, false);
            View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, parent, false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.txtArtist = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            holder.txtVolume = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
            holder.txtNumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            holder.buttonHeart = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.heart);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
            return rowView;
        }


        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtArtist;
            TextView txtVolume;
            TextView txtNumber;
            ImageButton buttonHeart;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to tell one thing, here if i am like holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlist); like this means, image changing but , when i  am scrolling the listview its resetting into previous only.

Comment: If I am giving the above line also no use.. for time being its changing icon but once i scroll down the list no changes happening, its resetting

Comment: @YamunaDevi go to `File` menu and select `Invalidate Caches and Restart` and select `Restart`.

Comment: No my issue is once i added that product to wish list, i will get the response value from api as true, so, if i refresh that class then that added value may updated in UI. I tried invalidate and restart also.

Comment: @YamunaDevi did you debug if not then debug and check where is the Problem line ..because if you refresh then the server value change so the problem is in your code. just debug it..

Comment: Yeah, problem is once i added the product into wish list then that product adding into wish list, and image changing from empty wishlist to filled wished list icon, but once i scroll down the image is replacing with emptywishlist icon, so if i clicked again on that wishlist image, again that product adding into wishlist api

Comment: If you click wishlist_image icon the it change the `Image` and set Value to `server` I think this you were solve it..

Comment: sorry i am questioning you to much.....I restricted adding the same product in wish list more than once, so now my issue only that adding/ removing wishlist icon symbol changing..

Comment: yeah when i clicked one item to wishlist in Api its changing value from 0 to 1 / 1 to 0, but issue id once the value set to 1, then how can i reflect that api response again?

Comment: yes...see in the above code, if and else condition once please.

Comment: Okay sure i will wait

Comment: @YamunaDevi I have posted the logic .

Comment: if (stat == 0) {
                        nav.addTowishList(wishList_url);// adding to wishlist
            notifyDataSetChanged():holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlist);


                    } else {
                        nav.removeFromwishList(remove_wishList_url); // removing from wishlist
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                       // holder.wish_list.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_wishlist);
                       
                     

          }

Comment: I am giving like this only

Comment: @YamunaDevi ya like this way but change `setImageResource` to `setImageDrawable` as i mention in my Answer..

Comment: @YamunaDevi because in your `if else` you are not send `state` value to `server` and also debug where it is not work..

Comment: I am adding that product to wish list , for that Api no parameters to send the status value... this i smy response once i added the product to wishlist {"responseCode":"1","msg":"Add Product to wishlist Successfully"}

Comment: Your saving the values into db so no issue, but here i retreiving value from api, so once i added that product into db i ahve to refresh adapter, then only if i clicked that product again, i can remove from wishlist

Comment: single item detailview with listadapter position data passing from list to detailview on extras.if user make any changes on detailview on status things how to update on list with out calling webservice once again please help me